# Is the Pythagorean distance not sufficient evidence that spacetime is not quantised/discrete?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, discrete

I think physicists believe space-time to be continuous. Is it still just a belief though? If we travel from one point to another point along the sides of a right triangle, and then try it again by using the diagonal, then we can confirm that spacetime is not quantised by confirming that the time taken obeys the Pythagoras theorem. Does this simple experimental fact not prove that spacetime is continuous?

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem is violated whenever spacetime is curved i.e. everywhere. It's just that on the lab scale the violation is too small to be easily measured. On larger scales the violation of Pythagoras' theorem is responsible for gravitational lensing.

Comment: how could you know it obeys pythagorean theorem? All measurements have errors. At best, you can say space is smooth at least up to a certain scale, but beyond that you cannot know.

Comment: @Umaxo In taxicab geometry, the distance along the diagonal is the same as the distance along the sides. So we could conclude that the universe is at least not taxicab as the diagonal distances are found to be much shorter in the actual experiments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider checking Pythagoras' theorem on an ordinary solid. One could measure distances and one would get accurate agreement. But the solid material itself is not smooth, because of the atomic structure. So to get accuracy at the nanometre scale or below, one has to make sure the measurements do not follow the atomic structure in detail, but smooth over it. That is, one must take the straight line distance from one place to another, and not follow the undulations of the electron clouds. Or if one's measuring method does follow those undulations, then one would have to take that into account.

When we say that spacetime might not be smooth, the scale on which any lack of smoothness may happen is very small, of the order of the Planck scale. That's $10^{-35}$ m, so smaller than an atom by a factor $10^{25}$. Clearly no direct measurement we can take now would be able to notice that kind of fine structure. Also, talk of discreteness here has to be understood in the context of quantum theory. The discreteness would not be like classical granularity, because in the quantum case you can have superposition and interference. For example, the energy levels of the hydrogen atom are discrete, but the atom can be in a superposition of two or more energy levels, and therefore its average energy can in principle take any value at all. In this example there is a discrete set of simple states called stationary states or energy eigenstates, but the actual state can be any combination of them, with continuously varying weights.

Applying quantum ideas to spacetime itself seems like a natural step to take, so many studies have tried to take it. However it is not clear how exactly one should do it and the existing work faces many difficulties of mathematical and physical consistency. It seems clear that any talk of 'discreteness' or 'discontinuity' in spacetime itself is probably using those terms somewhat loosely, to give some of the flavour of quantum theory. In quantum theory discreteness is often to do with the way boundaries and interactions happen. For example, the energy levels of hydrogen are only discrete up to some finite level of approximation to do with the strength of the interaction between the atom and the surrounding electromagnetic field. Really each of them has a range of energy, described by a function which varies continuously over a range of energies called the natural linewidth. Any 'discreteness' in spacetime would be like that only more so---it would very likely be something much more subtle than a collection of granular bits or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

We studied the interplay between topology, geometry, and physics and found a relation with a typical Pythagorean like tone-scale (how to distribute ratios of 2:3 into ratios of 1:2). It is possible to  derive the eigenfunctions of semi-harmonic quantum oscillators (also, based on normalised Chern numbers: the quantum ordered states), and an equation for the disordered states. We propose deterministic eigenvalues, that are also based on a meta-analysis of many data including a description of Bose Einstein condensates, EPR, Hall effect and masses of elementary particles. And showed a quantised space.